# dev-c++ seems to not compiling what's inside a 'if'

Tags: compiler-errors, dev-c++

the project I was working for school is basically a tennis counter (dont mind the blank 'if's outside of the 'while', I'm still working on it), which have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    
    int giocatore1=0;
    int giocatore2=0;
    int punto;

    while(giocatore1!=40 && giocatore2!=40) {
        do 
        scanf("%d", &punto);
        if(punto=1) {
            if(giocatore1<30) {
                giocatore1+=15;
            } else giocatore1+=10;
        } else if(punto=2) {
            if (giocatore2<30) {
                giocatore2+=15;
            } else giocatore2+=10;
        }
    }
    
}
```

I was expecting it to compile it right, but it instead gives me those compilation errors:

```
In function 'int main()':
12  6   [Error] expected 'while' before '(' token
12  16  [Error] expected ';' before '{' token
16  44  [Error] 'ptintf' was not declared in this scope
17  5   [Error] 'else' without a previous 'if'
```

It seems like it just numbs out and doesn't read the commands inside of only the first 'if'. Help would be appriciated.

Comment: Remove the `do` line, this is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `do` misstyped and 2 `=` that should be `==`. This code should be fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   int giocatore1=0;
   int giocatore2=0;
   int punto;

   while(giocatore1!=40 && giocatore2!=40) {
        scanf("%d", &punto);
        if(punto==1) {
            if(giocatore1<30) {
                giocatore1+=15;
            } else giocatore1+=10;
        } else if(punto==2) {
            if (giocatore2<30) {
                giocatore2+=15;
            } else giocatore2+=10;
        }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! sorry if the error seemed quite stupid, I'm still learning :)

Comment: No problem. Since you still learning, I recommend using `<` instead of `!=` in the `while` conditions if you can, it's more error friendly. Select my response as the best one if you can :)